# How to render multiple times with React useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm trying to define a function in React on which the component has to be rendered multiple times because I'm changing the state multiple times inside the function itself. I know that the useState hook re-renders the component at the end of the function, so how can I make it re-render immediately after I set the new state? The code is something like this:

```
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  const getServerState = () => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Send something to the server and put the response on "response"
    if (response.customVar === "uploading") {
      setState(1);
      // Send another request to the server and wait for the response
      if (newResponse.customVar === "uploaded" && state === 1) {
        setState(2);
      } else {
        throw new Error("Error in uploading response");
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error("Error in response");
    }
  };

  const checkState() => {
    if (state === 0) return "Waiting for user click";
    else if (state === 1) return "Your file is being uploaded";
    else if (state === 2) return "Your file is ready!";
  };

  return (
    <div>
    {checkState()}
    <button onClick={getServerState}>
      Click me
    </button>
  </div>)
}
```

In the example above, I don't get any re-renders because the state changes to 1 "too late" and the *if* that checks whereas the state is 1 doesn't go through. Is there a solution to this? I can't use the useEffect hook cause the effect would be updating the state and that would cause a loop.

Comment: Are you trying to show the status of a user upload? Or are you trying to display the status of something from a server?

Comment: I didnt get why you can't use useEffect. Probably with proper conditionals you can achieve that. Do you already know wich fetch strategy are you gonna use?

Comment: @JasonMcFarlane  The second one, to make the question simple I left out everything regarding the server because I think it doesn't matter with respect to the multiple re-render in React. Let' say I'm first making a GET request on the URL 1 and it gives me a certain response, and if that response is "uploading" I want to show the status via a re-render and immediately after make a second request that will generate a second re-render based on the response I get

Comment: @Canta that's because if I use useEffect with [state] as second paremeter and the effect is the update of state itself (I would be calling it after the first state change), it will continue to call the useEffect function infinite times

Comment: So when your component mounts you have the state of 0, "Waiting for user click", then when the user clicks you either have a state of 1 "uploading" or 2 "file ready" ?

Comment: @JasonMcFarlane I can't reach the state with two because it stops with the first setState

Comment: @Sosnos not if you only change state from another state e.g: if(state != x) setState(x). In this case state will not change, preventing further calls to useEffect

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the state immediately after setState, instead of that, you need to define one temp boolean variable.

```
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  const getServerState = () => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var isUploaded = false;
    // Send something to the server and put the response on "response"
    if (response.customVar === "uploading") {
      setState(1);
      isUploaded = true;
      // Send another request to the server and wait for the response
      if (newResponse.customVar === "uploaded" && isUploaded) {
        setState(2);
      } else {
        throw new Error("Error in uploading response");
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error("Error in response");
    }
  };

  const checkState() => {
    if (state === 0) return "Waiting for user click";
    else if (state === 1) return "Your file is being uploaded";
    else if (state === 2) return "Your file is ready!";
  };

  return (
    <div>
    {checkState()}
    <button onClick={getServerState}>
      Click me
    </button>
  </div>)
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't work anyway because the state would become 2 immediately and the checkState function would not print the case of state === 1. I need to print all of them, not just the first and the last one.

Comment: you will see state 1 as well till you reqeust to the server and get the response for thw state 2

Comment: you can check temporarily to add {state} inside div container.

Comment: The problem isn't on the container, but it is on the re-rendering after changing the state. Because React doesn't re-render until the function finishes, wouldn't get the state with 1